# Slideout menu: touch enabled only on close

Tags: menu, mobile-web

I'm building a mobile first webapp. I want to add a slideout menu for the main navigation.

The main page of the app is an interactive map, as the user will be moving around on the map a lot, I must deactivate touch for opening the slideout menu, otherwise the user will be opening it by mistake quite often.

Using touch to slide out the menu is a nice feature for mobile users.
So, I was considering enabling touch for the rest of the site, and enabling it only for closing it on the map page. Would this seem confusing for the user ? Should I just stick to a button for toggling the slide out menu ?

**Edit**

I realized that my question is directly related to the library I'm using, as they don't all work the same.

I'm using [slideout.js](https://slideout.js.org/)

It seems [the author has adressed the issue](https://github.com/Mango/slideout/issues/140) by allowing a grabWidth so the menu slides out only if swiping from screen edges. Haven't gotten it to work yet though.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem, google maps has a slide out menu and of course its main page is an interactive map, the touch features work good.

Comment: The issue is the asked wants a "slide out" menu, as in you slide your finger from the edge of the screen. That will conflict with the free scrolling of the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with a button that (when pushed) reveals the side menu, or a pull-tab for the user to that's independent of the map scrolling. Conflicting UI mechanisms should be avoided.

**Example**

Replace "Pull Tab" with a more discreet UI object, such as a transparent hamburger menu, or static menu header.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRVivs.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>